# Why does it matter if I am mutating state in React useState hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I read everywhere, that mutating state in React can cause problem, for example the component won't re-render on state update, but the following code is working perfectly fine. The component re-renders every time there is a the state updates.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Mutator = () => {
  const [checks, setChecks] = useState({ 66: false });

  const rows = [{ id: 23 }, { id: 33 }, { id: 44 }, { id: 55 }];

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("check updates", checks);
  }, [checks]);

  const mutateMyCheck = () => {
    rows.forEach((row, i) => {
      checks[row.id] = checks[row.id] ? checks[row.id] + i : 1;
    });

    setChecks({ ...checks });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={mutateMyCheck}>Check</button>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(checks)}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

What is the point of not mutating the state then ? Or when does it really have an effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mutating state directly but you're also returning a new object via object spreading:

```
setChecks({ ...checks });
```

Since this creates a new object the component re-renders.

Comment: That. Plus, there's absolutely no reason to mutate the state on the attached example. The same could be achieved with `Array.prototype.map()` or `Array.prototype.reduce()`

Comment: True though more of a style preference, reduce doesn't really make it cleaner so didn't mention - `rows.reduce((obj, row, i) => ({
    ...obj,
    [row.id]: checks[row.id] ? checks[row.id] + i : 1,
  }), {})` Also if the rows are in the 1000s I wouldn't do a spread each iteration like that but would return the same object each time (mutated) as it is significantly slower, so in the case of 1000s+ would be similar to the mutating loop to be efficient.

Comment: In that exact case, it is a styling decision. But if consider possible consequences of state mutations, it stops being one; your state is different from what the DOM has rendered, or imagine you've got multiple hooks attached. Or just think about the confusion it brings.

Answer (score 0):

```
 mutateMyCheck(); mutateMyCheck();
```

That won't increase the checks twice.

In this case you should use a [reducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer).